# How to make Failsafe RetryPolicy handle ConstraintVoilationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, retrypolicy

I am trying to insert and update on a table, by reading messages from active mq triggered via separate threads each time. At times insert query fails because of ConstraintVoilationException. I want to do a retry as the code will consider the retry attempt as an update and ConstraintVoilationException won't appear.

However, RetryPolicy is not working on this exception. How can I customize it?

**Failsafe artifact version: net.jodah (2.3.3)**

Here is the code sample, where 'T' is the className of my entity.

```
@Transactional
processTxn(T t){
 RetryPolicy<T> rp =  RetryPolicy<T>.handle(ConstraintVoilationException.class).withMaxRetries(3);
 Failsafe.with(rp).run(() -> insertOrUpdateMethod(t));
}

@Transactional
insertOrUpdateMethod (T t){
 //Fetch instance of t from DB, if it exists - fire update on a few columns
 //else insert a new row
}
```

I have also tried this code with DataIntegrityVoilationException and SQLIntegrityConstraintVoilationException but the code doesn't retry after failure.

Comment: Where you have written this code, in ExceptionHandler?

Comment: @Gaurav this method is in a service class (annotated with @Service) and being called via REST web service from another app that is polling ActiveMq (@JmsListener)

Comment: If getting DataIntegrityVoilationException in ActiveMQ listener, means getting incorrect data or some data is inconsistent, what will handler do in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure but I think the

```
@Transactional
processTxn(T t){
```

is the problem. A ConstraintViolationException has to be followed by a rollback of the current transaction.
When You remove this @Transactional and use only the ID of your entity or a detached instance in the method processTxn then a new Transaction is opened in insertOrUpdateMethod and in the case of ConstraintViolationException in the next try a new transaction is used.

In this case you have to be careful that the transaction in insertOrUpdateMethod is a new transaction and not a reused transaction  from a caller of processTxn.

Cheers
Peter Schütt